# Data not saving in Model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I've made a Model Form for a model I have, I cannot directly save data to model because I have a custom format date field which can only be made in forms.py with `forms.DateField(input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS)` but for some reason the data I'm parsing through the views is not saving in the model.

views.py

```
def applications_view(request):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        applications = LeaveApplication.objects.all()
        if request.method == "POST":
            id = request.POST.get('applications_id')
            user = request.POST.get('applications_user')
            reason = request.POST.get('applications_reason')
            from_date = request.POST.get('applications_from_date')
            to_date = request.POST.get('applications_to_date')
            if request.POST.get('approve'):
                something = LeaveList(user=user, reason=reason, from_date=from_date,
                 to_date=to_date, leave_status='Approve')
                leave_list_form = LeaveListForm(request.POST, instance=something)
                if leave_list_form.is_valid():
                    leave_list_form.save()             
            elif request.POST.get('deny'):
                something = LeaveList(user=user, reason=reason, from_date=from_date,
                 to_date=to_date, leave_status='Denied')
                leave_list_form = LeaveListForm(request.POST, instance=something)
                if leave_list_form.is_valid():
                    leave_list_form.save()          
        context = {
            'applications': applications
        }
        return render(request, 'home/applications.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
class LeaveListForm(forms.ModelForm):
    from_date = forms.DateField(input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS)
    to_date = forms.DateField(input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS)
    class Meta:
        model = LeaveList
        fields = [
            'user',
            'reason',
            'from_date',
            'to_date',
            'leave_status'
        ]
```

I'm not rendering form with context on the template because I'm looping over data from another model which I'm fetching again with a button with the help of a hidden type input which is rendered with every loop.

```
<table style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <th>Request ID</th>
                    <th>Employee</th>
                    <th>Reason for Leave</th>
                    <th>From Date</th>
                    <th>To Date</th>
                    <th>Approve/Deny</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ applications.id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ applications.user }}</td>
                    <td>{{ applications.reason }}</td>
                    <td>{{ applications.from_date }}</td>
                    <td>{{ applications.to_date }}</td>
                    <td>
                    <form method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input type="hidden" id="applications_id" name="applications_id" value="{{ applications.id }}">
                    <input type="hidden" id="applications_user" name="applications_user" value="{{ applications.user }}">
                    <input type="hidden" id="applications_reason" name="applications_reason" value="{{ applications.reason }}">
                    <input type="hidden" id="applications_from_date" name="applications_from_date" value="{{ applications.from_date }}">
                    <input type="hidden" id="applications_to_date" name="applications_to_date" value="{{ applications.to_date }}">
                    <input class="appproveButton appproveButtonYes" type="submit" name="approve" value="Approve">
                    <input type="submit" class="appproveButton appproveButtonNo"name="deny" value="Deny">
                    </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Comment: What is the format of settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS and what are you passing in request.POST.get('applications_from_date') ?

Comment: @KasimSharif DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%b. %d, %Y'] and for 'applications_from_date' its Feb. 24, 2021 (example)

Comment: Why do you do this `leave_list_form = LeaveListForm(request.POST, instance=something)` prior to saving. Also, it seems as if its likely your validation is failing, meaning your `save()` is never called. Have you checked if the form is passing validation?

Comment: I thought ```leave_list_form = LeaveListForm(request.POST, instance=something)``` would save the data in the fields. I had validation error earlier but not anymore after adding ```if leave_list_form.is_valid():``` so I think the form is passing validation.

Comment: No. That will not save the data. `something.save()` would if validation has passed. Add an `else:` to your `if form.isvalid()` and  see if it is passing. It seems likely that it is not.

Comment: @PacketLoss Doing ```something.save()``` gives me```['“Feb. 23, 2021” value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format.']```, same error trying to save data directly to model. This is why I had to make the form.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using your form why even handle getting the data? Simply pass the POST data to the form and let it handle it. Also it seems you don't want to get the leave_status from the form and instead pass a different key in the form for that, If that is the case just remove them from your form and handle it yourself:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect


def applications_view(request):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        applications = LeaveApplication.objects.all()
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = LeaveListForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                if request.POST.get('approve'):
                    leave_status = 'Approve'
                elif request.POST.get('deny'):
                    leave_status = 'Denied'
                else:
                    leave_status = 'SOME_DEFAULT_VALUE'
                form.instance.leave_status = leave_status
                form.save()
                return redirect('<SOME_URL_NAME>') # Redirect after successful form save!
        context = {
            'applications': applications,
        }
        return render(request, 'home/applications.html', context)
```

Now since you use a different view to render the form:

```
def other_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = LeaveListForm()
    # rest of view
    context = {..., 'form': LeaveListForm()}
    return render(request, 'some_template.html', context)
```

In your form:

```
class LeaveListForm(forms.ModelForm):
    from_date = forms.DateField(input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS) # Make sure the input formats are correct
    to_date = forms.DateField(input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS)
    class Meta:
        model = LeaveList
        fields = [
            'user',
            'reason',
            'from_date',
            'to_date',
        ] # Removed leave_status from here
```

Also it appears that you are directly rendering the form yourself by writing html. Even if you want to do that you need to work with the form in mind and set the names of the inputs to what the form would expect! Either simply leave the form rendering to django or correct your input tags names. I would suggest leaving the form rendering to django:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" name="approve" value="Approve">
    <input type="submit" name="deny" value="Deny">
</form>
```

If you don't like the way Django renders forms and want to customize it there are lots of great packages out there to help you do that, for e.g. [django-widget-tweaks](https://pypi.org/project/django-widget-tweaks/) and [django-crispy-forms](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Thanks but the reason I'm fetching the data with name tags is because I'm not rendering the form on the template with context. Can you instead help me with knowing how can I save this fetched data into the form?

Comment: @udaykls I have edited the answer do check. You can simply pass the form in the other view and render the form there. The form is a separate instance anyway and is validated from the post data here. If you want to customize how your form looks check the packages I recommend in the answer or you can also do some modification yourself by making custom templates and passing some parameters to the fields in the forms class.

Comment: @udaykls If you insist on rendering the form manually then still render the form automatically once using Django and check what name attribute you need to set for each of the inputs and then corresponding to that write your form inputs.

Comment: About the rendering form, I've edited my question. So I'm showing data on template with for loop and I need to get that looped data with help of a button so I'm using input with hidden type with every loop and showing data separately which all works flawlessly so I cannot render data even if I want to unless I want to change the value. For the rendering automatically once and set name to form inputs, I would still have to manually save data to modelform, right? Let me know if I didn't get you correctly.

Comment: @udaykls Now this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) if you would have informed us what you wanted to do you wouldn't have wasted so much time... Basically you 1) Already have an instance of another model. 2)  Seems like you want to just copy the data of this model and save it as it is either accepted or rejected. What I would like to say is why even POST all of the models data?? You can simply send the id of that model and get the instance in your view...

Comment: @udaykls Another thing I would like to say is why even have all the data of this model in your model `LeaveList`? You can simply have a foreign key to this model from your model `LeaveList` and be done with it! The data is already present in the other model!

Comment: Sorry for the half information but your comment gave me an idea. So I'm just fetching the id of the instance from template then creating an object in view getting that id's instance from the first model and assigning all fields from that one model to other model's fields. Thanks for your help.